# Return reference to anonymous method defined in increment call

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, memory-efficient

Simple syntactical question I can't seem to work out, I have a method which constructs a conditional event from a predicate and result, very simple call for code cleanliness and reusability.

```
public ValueUpdateEventHandler AddCondition(Func<float,bool> predicate, Action result)
{
    ValueUpdateEventHandler func = (float value) => { if (predicate(value)) result(); };
    onValueUpdate += func;
    return func;
}
```

I would like to condense it to a single return statement, which accomplishes the construction and assignment all at once kind of like

```
return onValueUpdate += (float value) => { if (predicate(value)) result(); };
```

but this returns the entire `onValueUpdate` delegate. Is there away to return a reference to the anonymous member on the right of the function, which is added to the named member, instead of returning the named member, but accomplish it in a single clean line? This is more for readability, as this is a single usecase of a pattern I intend to implement repeatedly

Comment: What is the type of onValueUpdate?

Comment: No, you can't really make it more succinct by reducing the number of statements. You can always do things in one line by just removing the newlines from the code, but I don't think that's what you're really after.